# Notification sound suddenly does not play anymore

Tags: sound, audio, notifications

Notifications appear without sound, I tried changing theme, turn off/on do-not-disturb, everything else works fine. Only notifications have no sound.

Answer (score 0):

I already try disabling by activating the notification sounds of the applications in settings[image]

Comment: it didnt work, all settings in the notifications panel are turned on.